# Connect to other devices under same AP isolated network

Tags: ssh, forwarding

I am trying to debug my android application under a public wifi network. The network seemed to have AP isolation on so I can't connect to my android device using my notebook.

However, both of my devices could connect to my SSH server.

How could ssh port forwarding helps me to debug my app?

Comment: Is your android application listening on a known port for requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your android application is listening for requests on a known port.

To access it, use **Remote Port Forwarding**. If the app on your android device is listening on port 12345, the hostname of your SSH server is "foo.bar.baz", and your username on this host is "foobar", then run the following from your android device:

```
ssh -R 12345:localhost:12345 foobar@foo.bar.baz
```

Then, from your notebook, you can access your android application at port 12345 on the host foo.bar.baz.